# Remove page from PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm currently using iText and I'm wondering if there is a way to delete a page from a PDF file?

I have opened it up with a reader etc., and I want to remove a page before it is then saved back to a new file; how can I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The 'better' way to 'delete' pages is doing

```
reader.selectPages("1-5,10-12");
```

Which means we only select pages 1-5, 10-12 effectively 'deleting' pages 6-9.

Answer (score 12):

Get the reader of existing pdf file by

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("source pdf file path");
```

Now update the reader by

```
 pdfReader.selectPages("1-5,15-20");
```

then get the pdf stamper object to write the changes into a file by

```
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader,
                new FileOutputStream("destination pdf file path"));
```

close the PdfStamper by

```
pdfStamper.close();
```

It will close the PdfReader too.

Cheers.....

Comment: Pretty sure you wanted that second block of code to read 'pdfReader.selectPages...', right?

Answer (score 2):

For iText 7 I found this example:

```
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(PATH + name + ".pdf");
    PdfDocument srcDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);
    PdfDocument resultDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(PATH + name + "_cut.pdf"));
    resultDoc.initializeOutlines();

    srcDoc.copyPagesTo(1, 2, resultDoc);

    resultDoc.close();
    srcDoc.close();
```

See also here: [clone-reordering-pages](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/stamping-content-existing-pdfs/clone-reordering-pages)
and here: [clone-splitting-pdf-file](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/stamping-content-existing-pdfs/clone-splitting-pdf-file)

Comment: @Zoba Why did you capitalize the `InitializeOutlines` and `Close` methods? As you can see above, the question is tagged [tag:java], so solutions must first be assumed to be Java solutions. And in iText / Java those methods start with lowercase letters...

Comment: @mkl oh, that was my fault - massive brain derp! I was in full c# mode there!

Comment: Thank you for posting it in c#! So few people program in Java... and converting the code to C# from Java is a PITA.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `PdfStamper` in combination with `PdfCopy`.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213067/how-to-show-a-limited-number-of-pages-of-pdf-file-in-jsp-using-itext/7223782#7223782) answer it is explained how to copy a whole document. If you change the criteria for the loop in the sample code you can remove the pages you don't need.

Comment: No, there is an easier way, which i'll post later.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a removing function ready for real life usage. Proven to work ok with `itext 2.1.7`. It does not use "strigly typing" also.

```
/**
 * Removes given pages from a document.
 * @param reader    document
 * @param pagesToRemove pages to remove; 1-based
 */
public static void removePages(PdfReader reader, int... pagesToRemove) {
    int pagesTotal = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    List<Integer> allPages = new ArrayList<>(pagesTotal);
    for (int i = 1; i <= pagesTotal; i++) {
        allPages.add(i);
    }
    for (int page : pagesToRemove) {
        allPages.remove(new Integer(page));
    }
    reader.selectPages(allPages);
}
```