# Create PDF by copying it from template with PdfCopy (lost of data)

Tags: c#, pdf, copy, itext

I'm trying to create a new pdf file based on another one using PdfCopy.
Everything work fine during generation and the generated file can be opened without any problem on my desktop, but the file seems to be corrupted and isn't accepted by the service that I must use :

> SignService error when calling 'sign', probably caused by a bad file format.

I noticed that the generated pdf is always ligther than the original template, so i compared the template version with the generated one. There are some big parts of missing data, especially a whole bunch of xml. I guess PdfCopy does not copying every of my original pdf but i cannot figured out what am i missing.

here is my method :

```
byte[] completedDocument = null;
string originalUri = Path.Combine(this.PdfPath, pdfName);
string generatedUri = Path.Combine(this.PdfGeneratedPath, generatedPdfName);

        using(MemoryStream streamCompleted = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using(Document doc = new Document())
            {
                PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(doc, streamCompleted);

                copy.PdfVersion = PdfWriter.VERSION_1_6;
                doc.Open();
                copy.Open();

                byte[] mergedDocument = null;
                PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(originalUri);
                int pdfPageNumber = pdfReader.NumberOfPages;

                using(MemoryStream streamTemplate = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, streamTemplate))
                    {
                        AcroFields acrofields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

                        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, AcroFields.Item> field in acrofields.Fields)
                        {
                            string data;
                            if (pdfFieldsValues.TryGetValue(field.Key, out data))
                            {
                                if (data == null)
                                {
                                    data = string.Empty;
                                }

                                acrofields.SetField(field.Key, data);
                            }
                        }

                        pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
                        pdfStamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
                    }

                    mergedDocument = streamTemplate.ToArray();
                }

                pdfReader = new PdfReader(mergedDocument);

                for (int page = 1; page <= pdfPageNumber; page++)
                {
                    if (!excludedPages.Any(s => s == page))
                    {
                        copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, page));
                    }
                }

                doc.Close();
                copy.Close();
            }

            completedDocument = streamCompleted.ToArray();
        }

        File.WriteAllBytes(generatedUri, completedDocument);
```

I tried to upload the "mergedDocument" rather than the "completedDocument" and my service accepting it, so i'm pretty sure it has something to do with this part :

```
for (int page = 1; page <= pdfPageNumber; page++)
{
    if (!excludedPages.Any(s => s == page))
    {
        copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, page));
    }
}
```

Or pdfCopy init

Comment: Instead of creating a new document and importing only the pages you want could you instead try just deleting the pages you don't want? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8751668/231316

Comment: *the service that I must use* - please explain the requirements this service has concerning the PDF file. If there are none, ask the service provider what causes the error.

Comment: Please do not edit your post to "add a solution", it is against the policy and intention of Stack Overflow. (Which you may not know because you did not read the Introductory Tour when signing up...) Just add your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start with a form. You fill out the form and you flatten it. By flattening it, you **deliberately** throw away all interactivity. I'm surprised that you're surprised that the file is getting smaller: you're throwing away the form infrastructure!

You then upload the flattened file to some service unknown to us. This service complains:

> SignService error when calling 'sign', probably caused by a bad file format.

As we don't know which service you are talking about, we can only guess. An educated guess would be that the original form contains a signature field that needs to be signed by a signing service.

Obviously that field is gone: **you flattened the form!** I may be wrong, but I assume that the service also tries to read the fields you filled out, but that won't be possible either as you throw away all interactivity. Please **remove** the following line:

```
pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
```

Then there's Chris' comment: it seems that you're using `PdfCopy`. If you're using an old version of iTextSharp (before iText 5.5.1), you shouldn't expect the form to be preserved. If you are using a recent version, you should instruct `PdfCopy` to preserve the form (but that line is missing). You don't need to ask *'how do I preserve the form?'* because you shouldn't be using `PdfCopy` anyway.

You only need `PdfStamper`. You already use `PdfStamper` to fill out the fields, now you can also use the `selectPages()` method to select the pages you want to keep (or to exclude the ones you want to remove).

Finally, it is unclear what you mean when you write:

> There are some big parts of missing data, especially a whole bunch of xml.

Are you saying that the form isn't a pure AcroForm, but that it also contains an XFA stream? If so, then you most definitely can't use `PdfCopy`.

Comment: Well I must admit i'm not very familiar with iTextSharp and PDF, I may have done some mistakes.
Now I use the selectPages() method as Chriss Hase and you mentionned it and it's work like a charm !