# How to cut last page from PDF on linux server

Tags: linux, pdf

I've more than 500 PDF files stored on linux server with 5 pages each. I want only first 4 pages in each file. Is there any way to cut last page from all 500 PDF pages on linux ?

Comment: Please elaborate. How do you want to do that - using some programming language or using some tool ??

Comment: In case you want to use some tool [do have a look](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221962/how-can-i-extract-a-page-range-a-part-of-a-pdf)

Comment: any option which will help to cut pdf is open. I'm using LAMP environment.

Comment: @SurajeetBharati thanks for sharing link; i'm looking for something automated way without manual intervention.

Comment: Ok. then you should go for some programming. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312824/itext-remove-page-from-pdf) .. You can use Java `api`s like **iText** or **PdfBox**.

Comment: Thank You ; I manged to cut page using latex class

Answer (score 3):

You can us the tool `pdftk` (need to be installed)

To only have page 1-4 from the `in.pdf`  in your `out.pdf` file you have to type

```
pdftk in.pdf cat 1-4 output out.pdf
```

`pdftk` is a very powerfull tool, which can do a number of pdf manipulations. Have a look at the man page. At the end of the man pages are some examples of the most common tasks.

Comment: unfortunately i don't have pdftk installed. Let me check option to get it installed.